# Angular2- Meteor, npm package not recognized

Tags: angular, meteor, npm, webstorm, package

I am a newbie, trying to use kiteconnect npm pacakge inside my angular2-meteor app, but when I try to import this package in my app.module.ts it says Cannot find module 'KiteConnect'.
Below is the statement I am using below import statement

```
import {KiteConnect}   from 'KiteConnect';
```

I am sure this is something very silly but could someone please point me what I am doing wrong here.

Below is extract from my package.json

```
{
  "name": "socially",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha",
    "test:ci": "meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.2",
    "angular2-meteor": "0.7.0",
    "angular2-meteor-accounts-ui": "^1.0.0",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "0.1.1",
    "angular2-meteor-tests-polyfills": "0.0.2",
    "kiteconnect": "^1.1.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "0.2.3",
    "meteor-rxjs": "0.4.3",
    "meteor-typings": "1.3.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.33",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.32",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-spies": "0.7.1"
  }
}
```

I also tried with package "chalk" but again same issue while importing. Now I doubt whether it is because of the editor (I am using webstorm) or due to tsconfig.josn which is as below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "files": [
    "typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can add the extract from your `packages.json`?

Comment: @LibinVarghese,

Comment: @LibinVarghese, I have updated the package.json in my question

Answer (score 0):

try using var `KiteConnect = require('kiteconnect').KiteConnect;` after calling `meteor npm install kiteconnect`

Comment: Yes, but I first need to inject the dependencies in @NgModuleand so taht I can use it in my component of angular2, for this I first need to import kiteConnect, but this is not recognizing in the import statement

Comment: Weird. I just put `import { KiteConnect } from 'KiteConnect';
console.log(new KiteConnect());` at the top of my router.js file and it worked. Did you call `meteor npm install`? What else are you doing?

Comment: wierd indeed, I used "Meteor npm install --save kiteconnect" and I can see kiteconnect in node modules, but I cannot access it with import statement. I am using " import { KiteConnect } from 'KiteConnect'; " at app.module.ts which is my entry file in my angular2 application